# Translation for "Woodlouse"

Tags: vocabulary, proper-nouns

What is the best simplified Chinese translation for the isopod known as the common European "Woodlouse", also called "Sow bug" or "Pill bug" in US?

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse for details)

Comment: Simple google search? 潮虫 or 鼠妇.

Comment: Go with @倪阔乐. Also An isopod isn't an insect... It has probably 200 names in China. In my town we call it 钵鞋虫 because it looks like a monk's shoe. The name 西瓜虫 is reserved to those that can curl; Not all of them can.

Comment: Tried google 1st but when entering to baidu its not clear its correct.

Comment: Thanks Wang have edited for isopod, sorry was not expecting such an entomologically correct answer, and added picture reference. I would mark 西瓜虫 as correct if your comment was an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called 鼠妇 in writing phrase，also some nickname which is 西瓜虫 潮虫 团子虫 etc